# Read Log from external memory

Tags: c

I log records in external memory. Every record takes \$2\$ bytes. Now I need to read \$N\$ last records in chunks of \$18\$ bytes, so I did something like this.

```
uint32_t chank = 18;  //DELTA_SIZE * AVAILABLE_BUF_SIZE;
uint32_t last_log_addr = (logNum * DELTA_SIZE) + START_LOG_ADRESS;
uint32_t packet_size;
uint32_t current_addr = last_log_addr;  

//check if the overflow occurred
while (current_addr > START_LOG_ADRESS)
{
    packet_size = chank;


    uint8_t buf[packet_size];

    LOGGER_Readlog(current_addr,packet_size,buf);

    SendBuf(buf);

    current_addr -= chank; 
}
// send the rest of data ???
```

However, I think the algorithm and subsequent code can be improved.

Answer (score 2):

1. `while (current_addr > START_LOG_ADRESS)` certainly should be `>=`.  The loops appears to be sending 1 "chuck" passed the intended address.  IAC, more idiomatic to use a for loop

   ```
   uint32_t current_addr;
   for (current_addr = START_LOG_ADRESS; current_addr<last_log_addr; current_addr += chank){
      uint8_t buf[chank];
      LOGGER_Readlog(current_addr, packet_size, buf);
      SendBuf(buf);
   }
   ```
2. Suspect "chunk" is meant rather than "chank".
3. `SendBuf(buf)` is suspicious in that the length is not passed.